# MIFARE Cards replicate on Android device

Tags: android, mifare

Is it possible to replicate the whole functionality of the MIFARE classic cards in android ? for example, instead of using a card, I can use my android device to communicate to the reader. 
If there is, is there any good resources to look at? I am pretty new at this. 
Does it need host-based emulation or embedded secure element?